# .Net 4.0 WPF RichTextBox vs. Extended WPF Toolkit RichTextBox and unicode

Tags: wpf, encoding, wpf-controls, binding, richtextbox

I have a FlowDocument, that I want to display in a readonly RichTextBox. This has to happen via DataBinding, since it is displayed in each of my DataGrid's rows. That's why I ended up with the RichTextBox that comes with the Extended WPF Toolkit.

Text text I intend to display has the following simple markup:

```
<Section xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Paragraph>
        <TextBlock Text="it" Background="#FF90EE90" />
        <TextBlock Text="'" FontWeight="Bold" Background="#FFE9967A" />
        <TextBlock Text="s a snake" Background="#FF90EE90" />
    </Paragraph>
</Section>
```

What the RTB displays is the following:

[image: messed up encoding]

I have made sure to use a unicode-compatible font, so this is not the issue. Furthermore, I have cross-checked with the regular RichTextBox - All gets displayed fine, although I have to set the document programmatically (lack of binding support).Also, the regular RTB has a Document property, so I had to replace the section tag with a flowdocument tag.

If I set ReadOnly to false, I can paste the unicode stuff in without any trouble, so I guess it's not a lack of support I'm facing here...Does anybody know how I can get the Extended Toolkit RichTextBox to display it's content in the right way?

TIA, Seb

Answer (score 0):

The RTB in Extended WPF Toolkit doesn't do anything different and actually is the Microsoft RTB with a Text property added to it.  I would be curious as to what the format of the source is.  Is the source properly formatted as RTF?  Could you provide the RTF value instead of the XAML value?

Comment: I don't work with the RTF format, all I use is XAML. Plain RTB gets a <document> set on it's Document property (content is the same as that of the section mentioned above), the Extended TK's RTB gets the <section> displayed in the question set on its Text property.